# How to launch with am start if receiving Could not launch the requested activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi so I am trying to access some secret menus through an adb shell which has worked on some of my older devices, for instance i run the following in a shell.`am start com.sec.hiddenmenu/.ServiceModeApp` The app pops up the immediately closes out and I get a popup with Could not launch the requested activity. Any pointers or ideas or solutions welcome I am pretty much a newb but would like to see if I can get this to work again. Thanks a ton for any help you can provide. Per request I used pastbin to add the appmanifest.xml which can be viewed here http://pastebin.com/ZVxd1SSs

Comment: Is this activity declared in manifest?

Comment: can you paste your manifest file code

Comment: add error log and more detail @toxinburn

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZVxd1SSs and yes activity is declared from what i can tell.